# Nginx Error after upgrading php

Tags: nginx, php

I have an aws server that runs some php code.

I recently upgraded to php8.  Now when I access php pages on my site (for example https://whitewaterwriters.com/oracle/index.php) I get a nginx error.

I look at the logs with  `sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log` and I get this:

`2022/11/22 10:43:23 [crit] 2309#2309: *12122 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 51.148.131.133, server: whitewaterwriters.com, request: "GET /oracle/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "whitewaterwriters.com"`

So it's looking for a socket at www.sock. There isn't such a socket (although I do have that socket on a different server that I'd swear I configured the same way)  The socket I have is php-frm.sock. That's the socket that the nginx.conf file refers to:

```
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include         fastcgi_params;
                }
```

and the one that php.ini listens on (at /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf)

`listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`

My question is: what is the config file that is telling nginx to look for a www.sock? Or how do I create that socket?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the answer to "Where is the config file?" was

/etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf - it was pointing to www.conf wheneverthing else wasn't.